# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1

Tags: android, gradle

When I run a project I get the error:

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

my gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that the android tools plugin you want to use has moved. Old distributions are in jcenter, but new ones are at "https://maven.google.com"

Update your repositories to include "https://maven.google.com"

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has worked for me

Answer (score 7):

If you are in iran, china, etc... delete .gradle folder from android folder then try again with VPN.

Answer (score 5):

Go to your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in `build.gradle` and you will see the last line that specifies *distributionUrl*. Replace *distributionUrl* with below one.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Let the download finish and your problem will be resolved. If you want to avoid the download reduce the version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1` this to 4.0.0+ or 3.0.0+

Answer (score 3):

in iran, china, north korea , Afghanistan delete .gradle and gradle folder from android folder then try again with VPN and download gradle

Answer (score -2):

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Please add above under dependencies